# Different MD5 hash with the same value

Tags: php, pdo, hash, md5, registration

I'm making a registration page, and I encrypt users' password with md5, when I made the login page everytime I tried to logged in it said wrong password, so I checked if the md5 hash is the same as in the database, but it's not, and I'm sure the password is correct. I use the same code in the login page and the registration page too: `$password = md5($password)`

Comment: the question is "why" are you using MD5? it isn't safe to use anymore for password storage, use `password_hash()/password_verify()`

Comment: I'd guess your column is too short to store the full hash. Also note `md5` is not an encryption and is out dated. Adding your code might help the question.

Comment: I try with password_hash
BTW, I made it for myself, just for fun, I don't really care about the securty, but thanks for the info

Comment: *"I try with password_hash"* - MD5 and `password_hash()`'d pw's are two different animals. The question is unclear and lacks detail/code etc. *"I don't really care about the securty"* - You should.

Comment: Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force. For PHP the easiest and secure method is to use `password_hash` and `password_verify`.

Comment: @DanieleManna While you many not care about security your users probably do and expect good security.

Comment: I moved to 'password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options)' in options I have: '"cost" => 11' and '"salt" => mcrypt_create_iv(22, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)' but the hash generated at the login page is still different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making it more complicated than necessary. See: [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

> Note: Caution
>   It is strongly recommended that you **do not** generate your own salt for this function. It will create a secure salt automatically for you if you do not specify one.

See: [Hashing Passwords with the PHP](https://www.sitepoint.com/hashing-passwords-php-5-5-password-hashing-api/)

Create password hash:

```
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Be sure to store the hash in a column that’s capacity is beyond 60 characters.

Verify password:

```
if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
    // Success!
}
else {
    // Invalid credentials
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you for your patience and your help!